# Is it possible to make Craft/Twig throw 404 if a template can't be found?

Tags: templating, error-handling

Attempting to include a template that doesn't exist throws HttpStatus 500 – `Craft\TemplateLoaderException – Unable to find the template “{template}”.`

This is usually fine and what you want, but is it possible to override this behaviour somehow, and make Craft throw a plain' old 404 instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it – not super elegant, but it works:

```
{% set template %}
    {{- include('sometemplatethatdoesntexist', ignore_missing = true) -}}
{% endset %}

{% if not template %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{{ template }}
```